# Is it possible to call client from codebase (server) without using another hub client?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

Here is simple SignalR app example: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs

I've got this class

```
  public class Chat : Hub 
  {
       public void Send(string message)
      {
          // Call the addMessage method on all clients            
          Clients.All.addMessage(message);
      }
  }
```

But I don't create an object anywhere by myself so I don't know how to call `Send` from server side?

There is a way by using

`HubConnection("http://localhost/mysite")` -> `chat.Invoke("Send", line).Wait();`

But it's looking for me a bit overhead. My main task it to provide an event coming from server to client side so is it possible to make it without using `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client` and `HubConnection` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to call your Hub Send method from outside of the hub itself. Instead do this:

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Chat>().Clients.All.addMessage(message)
```